# How to sort on time property using Angular.js and ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

This is my sample data

```
  {
    "day": "Sunday",
    "count": [{
        "desc": "sunday one event"
    }, {
        "j": [{
            "start": "11:00 pm"
        }, {
            "end": "11:51 pm"
        }]
    }, {
        "desc": "sunday second event"
    }, {
        "j": [{
            "start": "12:00 am"
        }, {
            "end": "12:06 am"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to show the above data sorted on the time (UTC format) property using angular.js.

I have tried using `moment.js` but can't figure it out.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show the code.

Comment: Check MomentJS library https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Is your time data instance of Date object ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `moment('11/06/2017 11:00').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")` to format your Date Strings to Date objects using [`Moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/).

To sort your results make use of the `orderBy` option of the `ngRepeat` directive (or provide a custom `filter` if deeper filtering is needed):

```
{{ array | orderBy : expression}}
```

**View**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DateController as vm">
  <b>Events</b>
  <div ng-repeat="ev in vm.events | orderBy: 'date' ">
    {{::ev.name}} - {{::ev.date}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Or sort reverse by using `-`:

```
<div ng-repeat="ev in vm.events | orderBy: '-date' ">
```

**Controller**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
    .controller('DateController', DateController)

function DateController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.events = [
    {
        "name" : "sunday first event", 
      "date" : moment('11/06/2017 11:00').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
    },
    {
        "name" : "sunday third event", 
      "date" : moment('11/06/2017 16:00').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
    },
    {
        "name" : "sunday late event", 
      "date" : moment('11/06/2017 21:00').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
    },
    {
        "name" : "sunday second event", 
      "date" : moment('11/06/2017 12:00').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
    }    
  ];
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/Lz2pfmyc/)

Comment: but my date are of coming in this format `{"day":"Sunday","count":[{"desc":"sunday one event"},{"gj":[{"start":"11:00 pm"},{"end":"11:51 pm"}]},{"desc":"sunday second event"},{"gj":[{"start":"12:00 am"},{"end":"12:06 am"}]}]}` can"t able to do orderby